# Burn large ISO installer on multiple dual-layer DVDs

Tags: operating-system, iso, windows-installer

Hi I have a really large ISO installer (larger than one dual-layer DVD) and is there a way to burn it onto two DVDs? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Use an USB stick.

Comment: Why is it not possible??

Comment: First, you *naturally* would have not a valid filesystem if you just split the image. Second, the installer just can't handle multiple images unless it's specifically written to support this.